# I'm trying to get data from my realtime database temperature but i keep getting this error on my Event

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried changing the event to snapshot but the result is still the same any idea? I've also tried to use firebase_core but the problem still presist.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) {
      final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      databaseReference.child("temp").onValue.listen((Event event) {
        setState(() {
          _temperature = event.snapshot.value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "${_temperature.toString()}°")
```

Comment: "i keep getting this error" What error? Please edit your question to include the exact error message and the complete stack trace.